# can't totally uninstall pyqt4 in ipython

Tags: pyqt, ipython, pyqt4, pyqt5

I want to uninstall PyQt4 and install PyQt5. However, I can't make the ipython show the right package.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried go to you PyCharm just go to your settings -> interpreter -> and just update it? It should be simple like that.There will be a blue arrow u just click on it and update it.

[image: Interpreter options]